# Reset index with two values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I would like to set an index based on two columns. The two columns are named 'name' and 'date'.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=df[['name', 'date']]).reset_index().rename(
    columns={'index': 'name'})
```

Could you please advise me?

Cheers, Jeroen

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is what you mean.

```
  df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])
```

To pass more argument (e.g. inplace, drop columns etc.) check this link for more information: [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar'], 'date': ['2012', '2017']})

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   date name
0  2012  foo
1  2017  bar

In [44]: df.set_index(df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x)))
Out[44]: 
              date name
(2012, 2017)  2012  foo
(foo, bar)    2017  bar
```